# serializing a data class to json always results in null

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am trying to serialize a really simple Kotlin data class to json using the gson library. There is a good chance that there is some dead simple user error that I am missing, but for the life of me, I can't tell what it is. I have searched around and my snippet seems to match the examples. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.google.gson.*
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var gson = Gson()

    data class Msg(
        @SerializedName("body") val body: String = "",
        @SerializedName("keywords") val kwords: Array<String?>,
        @SerializedName("ner") val ner: Array<String?>)


    val msg = Msg("Test Body",arrayOf("key1","Key2"), arrayOf("ner1", "ner2"))


    val json = gson.toJson(msg)
    println(json)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote you example pulling `Msg` data class out of `main` function and... it works: it's a limitation of GSON library, as reported [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). If I don't misunderstand, the cause behind this choice is that internal classes should mantain a reference to external object, and this complicates the management of internal classes.

> However, Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is not available at the time of deserialization. You can address this problem by either making the inner class static or by providing a custom InstanceCreator for it. Here is an example:

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Works now.